# R Roxygen2 documentation without building a package

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2, code-documentation

I am currently programming within an R project. Right now there is no need for building a whole package, but I would like to use roxygen to create documentation of several functions nonetheless.

Whenever I am looking for "object documentation" or "roxygen", the context is immediately package development (e.g. https://r-pkgs.org/man.html).

Is it possible to document the functions using roxygen without building a package?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Isn't an R package just a well organized R project? Could you just adopt the package structure as a structure for your project?

Comment: Read this [Getting started with roxygen2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html)